# How to assess heterogeneity between fitted, correlated parameter values?

Tags: meta-analysis, pooling, heterogeneity

I have four datasets, and for each one, I fit the same 3-parameter model. I'm interested in making a statement about the heterogeneity of each parameter value of the model, across the four datasets (and also comparing it to parameters from a fit to the pooled dataset).

My first thought was to use Cochrane's $Q$ and $I^2$ to assess heterogeneity for each parameter, but the three parameters aren't independent - they are intrinsically linked in the model itself (essentially, the model is a probit function (2 parameters) using a generalized mean (1 parameter) as input, so the generalized mean parameter is going to be highly correlated with one of the probit parameters).

In some sense, I'm trying to compare the results of a traditional meta-analysis (combining the three parameter values from the 4 dataset fits) with a pooled analysis approach (the model parameter values fit from the combined dataset).

Any insight on what I'm missing would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since the three parameters are estimated from the same model they will be correlated and so a multivariate meta-analysis would be appropriate here. Since you are analysing each data-set yourself you can extract the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients from the analysis to use. Attempting to determine heterogeneity with only four studies is going to be difficult as methods have low power to detect it.

Multivariate meta-analysis is widely available in standard software like Stata and R.